# How to genericize a Java enum with static members?

Tags: java, generics, static, enums

I am refactoring a part of our legacy app which handles exporting and importing of DB tables from/to Excel sheets. We have a `Formatter` subclass for each table, to provide the definition of that table: how many columns it has, and what is the name, format and validator of each column. The getters which supply this data are then called by a Template Method which exports/imports the table. I have extracted the column data into an enum, which greatly simplified the code. A formatter now looks like this (some details omitted for brevity):

```
public class DamageChargeFormatter extends BaseFormatter {
    public static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 7;

    public enum Column {
        VEHICLE_GROUP(0, "Vehicle Group", /* more params */),
        NAME_OF_PART(1, "Name of Part", /* more params */),
        //...
        LOSS_OF_USE(6, "Loss of Use", /* more params */);

        private static final Map<Integer, Column> intToColumn = new HashMap<Integer, Column>();

        static {
            for (Column type : values()) {
                intToColumn.put(type.getIndex(), type);
            }
        }

        public static TableColumn valueOf(int index) {
            return intToColumn.get(index);
        }

        private int index;
        private String name;

        Column(int index, String name, /* more params */) {
            this.index = index;
            this.name = name;
            //...
        }

        public int getIndex() { return index; }

        public String getName() { return name; }

        // more members and getters...
    }

    protected String getSheetName() {
        return "Damage Charges";
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnNumber) {
        TableColumn column = Column.valueOf(columnNumber);

        if (column != null) {
            return column.getName();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // more getters...

    protected int getNumColumns() {
        return NUM_COLUMNS;
    }

    protected boolean isVariableColumnCount() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, I have about a dozen such classes, each of which containing exactly the same code except that `NUM_COLUMNS` and the enum values of `Column` are different. Is there any way to genericize this somehow? The main obstacle to this is the static `Column.valueOf()` method and the static constant `NUM_COLUMNS`. Another concern with latter is that it really belongs to an abstraction one level higher, i.e. to the table, not to an individual column - it would be nice to somehow incorporate this into the generic solution.

Technically I could solve this with a base interface (`TableColumn` below) and reflection, but I don't really like that, as apart from trading compile time errors to runtime errors, it makes the code ugly (to me):

```
public class GenericFormatter<E extends TableColumn> extends BaseFormatter {
    private Method valueOfMethod;

    public GenericFormatter(Class<E> columnClass) {
        try {
            valueOfMethod = columnClass.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", Integer.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnNumber) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            E elem = (E) valueOfMethod.invoke(columnNumber);

            if (elem != null) {
                return elem.getName();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //...
}
```

Note that this code is purely experimental, as yet untested...

Is there a nicer, cleaner, safer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, something like this:

```
public class TableMetadata<E extends Enum & TableColumn> {
    private Map<Integer, TableColumn> columns = new HashMap<Integer, TableColumn>();

    public TableMetadata(Class<E> c) {
        for (E e: c.getEnumConstants()) {
            columns.put(e.getIndex(), e);
        }
    }

    public String getColumnName(int index) {
        return columns.get(index).getName();
    }
}

public class GenericFormatter<E extends TableColumn> extends BaseFormatter {  
    private TableMetadata<E> m;  

    public GenericFormatter(TableMetadata<E> m) {  
         this.m = m;
    }  

    public String getColumnName(int columnNumber) {  
        return m.getColumnName(index);
    }  

    //...  
}
```

**EDIT:** `Enum` added to the type parameter for more compile-time safety

Comment: Excellent idea! You made it obvious that I was stuck in a mental rut, blindly assuming that the static lookup method is inside the enum. Thanks! :-)